# Unable to select an option from drodownlist using selenium remote driver in perl scripting

Tags: javascript, perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium::Remote::Driver module in perl Scripting. I am trying to select country from the dropdownlist in webpage which is not visible by selenium remote driver(dispaly as none),i have used so many methods but still it is not worked for me.can you please help me how to select that country from that dropdownlist.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Remote::WebElement;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);

my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver
$driver ->get($url);

eval{$driver->find_element('register_address_country','id');};
      if($@)
      {
         print "register adress country element not found \n";
      }
      else
      {
       print "element is found \n";
       my $script = q{

            var elem1 = window.document.findElementById(register_address_country);
            return elem1;
            };

              my $elem2=$driver->execute_script($script,'DE'); 
              $elem2->click();
           }
  }

#here the script is exited without performing any operation even the element is find
```

i am using this one also:

```
$driver->find_element("//select[\@id='register_address_country']/option[\@value='DE']")->click();

#here  the element is find but not perform any operation like click or select
```

i am using this one also:

```
eval{$driver->find_elements('span','tag_name');};
      if($@)
      {
         print "span tag_name elements are not found \n";
      }
      else
      {
         print "span tag elements are found \n";
         my @values=$driver->find_elements('span','tag_name');
         foreach my $r(@values)
         {
             print "rvalue:$r \n";
             my $text1=$r->get_text();
             print "text1:$text1 \n";
             if($text1 eq 'Please choose your country')
             {
                $r->click();
                print "selected \n";
                last;
             }
         }

      }


#here please choose text is find but not clicked that webelement
```

### HTML code :

```
<div class="controls">
<select id="register_address_country" class="address-country selectBox" name="addressCountry" style="display: none;">
<option value="" selected="selected" data-localize="values.copv2.content.pleaseChooseCountry">Please choose your country</option>
<option value="AR">Argentina</option>
<option value="AU">Australia</option>
<option value="AT">Austria</option>
<option value="BE">Belgium</option>
<option value="BR">Brazil</option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>
<option value="CL">Chile</option>
<option value="CN">China</option>
<option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="DK">Denmark</option>
<option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="EE">Estonia</option>
<option value="FI">Finland</option>
<option value="FR">France</option>
<option value="DE">Germany</option>
<option value="GR">Greece</option>
<option value="IN">India</option>
<option value="IL">Israel</option>
<option value="IT">Italy</option>
<option value="JP">Japan</option>
<option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="MX">Mexico</option>
<option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
<option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
<option value="NO">Norway</option>
<option value="PL">Poland</option>
<option value="PT">Portugal</option>
<option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
<option value="KR">South Korea</option>
<option value="ES">Spain</option>
<option value="SE">Sweden</option>
<option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
<option value="TR">Turkey</option>
<option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="US">United States</option>
<option value="">_____________________________</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AD">Andorra</option>
<option value="AO">Angola</option>
<option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
<option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="AR">Argentina</option>
<option value="AM">Armenia</option>
<option value="AW">Aruba</option>
<option value="AU">Australia</option>
<option value="AT">Austria</option>
<option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
<option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="BB">Barbados</option>
<option value="BY">Belarus</option>
<option value="BE">Belgium</option>
<option value="BZ">Belize</option>
<option value="BJ">Benin</option>
<option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
<option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
<option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
<option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="BW">Botswana</option>
<option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
<option value="BR">Brazil</option>
<option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
<option value="VG">British Virgin Islands</option>
<option value="BN">Brunei</option>
<option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="BI">Burundi</option>
<option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
<option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>
<option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="TD">Chad</option>
<option value="CL">Chile</option>
<option value="CN">China</option>
<option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
<option value="CC">Cocos Islands</option>
<option value="CO">Colombia</option>
<option value="KM">Comoros</option>
<option value="CD">Congo (Democratic Republic of)</option>
<option value="CG">Congo (Peoples Republic of)</option>
<option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
<option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="HR">Croatia</option>
<option value="CU">Cuba</option>
<option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
<option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
<option value="DK">Denmark</option>
<option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
<option value="DM">Dominica</option>
<option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="TL">East Timor</option>
<option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
<option value="EG">Egypt</option>
<option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
<option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
<option value="EE">Estonia</option>
<option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="FO">Faeroe Islands</option>
<option value="FK">Falkland Islands</option>
<option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
<option value="FI">Finland</option>
<option value="MK">Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia</option>
<option value="FR">France</option>
<option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
<option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
<option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
<option value="GA">Gabon</option>
<option value="GE">Georgia</option>
<option value="DE">Germany</option>
<option value="GH">Ghana</option>
<option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
<option value="GR">Greece</option>
<option value="GL">Greenland</option>
<option value="GD">Grenada</option>
<option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
<option value="GU">Guam</option>
<option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
<option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
<option value="GN">Guinea</option>
<option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
<option value="GY">Guyana</option>
<option value="HT">Haiti</option>
<option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
<option value="HN">Honduras</option>
<option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
<option value="HU">Hungary</option>
<option value="IS">Iceland</option>
<option value="IN">India</option>
<option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
<option value="IR">Iran</option>
<option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
<option value="IE">Ireland</option>
<option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
<option value="IL">Israel</option>
<option value="IT">Italy</option>
<option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
<option value="JP">Japan</option>
<option value="JO">Jordan</option>
<option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="KE">Kenya</option>
<option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
<option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
<option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="LA">Laos</option>
<option value="LV">Latvia</option>
<option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
<option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
<option value="LR">Liberia</option>
<option value="LY">Libya</option>
<option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
<option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="MO">Macau</option>
<option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
<option value="MW">Malawi</option>
<option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
<option value="MV">Maldives</option>
<option value="ML">Mali</option>
<option value="MT">Malta</option>
<option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
<option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
<option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
<option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
<option value="MX">Mexico</option>
<option value="FM">Micronesia</option>
<option value="MD">Moldova</option>
<option value="MC">Monaco</option>
<option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
<option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
<option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
<option value="MA">Morocco</option>
<option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
<option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
<option value="NA">Namibia</option>
<option value="NR">Nauru</option>
<option value="NP">Nepal</option>
<option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
<option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option>
<option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
<option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
<option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="NE">Niger</option>
<option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
<option value="NU">Niue</option>
<option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
<option value="KP">North Korea</option>
<option value="MP">Northern Marianas</option>
<option value="NO">Norway</option>
<option value="OM">Oman</option>
<option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
<option value="PW">Palau</option>
<option value="PA">Panama</option>
<option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
<option value="PE">Peru</option>
<option value="PH">Philippines</option>
<option value="PN">Pitcairn Islands</option>
<option value="PL">Poland</option>
<option value="PT">Portugal</option>
<option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="QA">Qatar</option>
<option value="RO">Romania</option>
<option value="RU">Russia</option>
<option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
<option value="RE">Réunion</option>
<option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
<option value="SH">Saint Helena</option>
<option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
<option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
<option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
<option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
<option value="WS">Samoa</option>
<option value="SM">San Marino</option>
<option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="SN">Senegal</option>
<option value="RS">Serbia</option>
<option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
<option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="SG">Singapore</option>
<option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
<option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
<option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="SO">Somalia</option>
<option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
<option value="GS">South Georgia</option>
<option value="KR">South Korea</option>
<option value="ES">Spain</option>
<option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="SD">Sudan</option>
<option value="SR">Suriname</option>
<option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
<option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
<option value="SE">Sweden</option>
<option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
<option value="SY">Syria</option>
<option value="ST">São Tomé and Príncipe</option>
<option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
<option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="TZ">Tanzania</option>
<option value="TH">Thailand</option>
<option value="BS">The Bahamas</option>
<option value="GM">The Gambia</option>
<option value="TG">Togo</option>
<option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
<option value="TO">Tonga</option>
<option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
<option value="TR">Turkey</option>
<option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
<option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
<option value="UM">US Minor Outlying Islands</option>
<option value="VI">US Virgin Islands</option>
<option value="UG">Uganda</option>
<option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
<option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="US">United States</option>
<option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
<option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="VA">Vatican City</option>
<option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
<option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
<option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
<option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
<option value="YE">Yemen</option>
<option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
<option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
<a class="selectBox address-country selectBox-dropdown" style="width: 100px; display: inline-block; -moz-user-select: none;" title="" tabindex="0">
<span class="selectBox-label" style="width: 64px;">Please choose your country</span>
<span class="selectBox-arrow"/>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm no familiar with the Perl bindings but do you have access to the `Select()` class? A quick Java example would be: `Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("register_address_country")); select.selectByValue("DE");` If you can transpose that into Perl, I would hope you're back on track.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and, while not an explanation of how this occurs, I was able to 'hack' my way around this by simply adding another click.

So your example would look like this:

```
print "span tag elements are found \n";
my @values=$driver->find_elements('span','tag_name');
foreach my $r(@values)
{
    print "rvalue:$r \n";
    my $text1=$r->get_text();
    print "text1:$text1 \n";
    if($text1 eq 'Please choose your country')
    {
       $r->click();
       $r->click();
       print "selected \n";
       last;
    }
}
```

Try it, it worked for me.